# Brutal increase in Firebase bandwidth, is it normal?

Tags: firebase

On Thursday the 21th of April we saw a massive increase in the Database Bandwidth for all our App, when we didn't made any logic changes:

[App 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlyB2.png), [App 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5baUt.png)

These 2 app are not related, so the increase must come for Firebase side !

For both the bandwidth was multiplied by around 4, so this is not something we can overlook (Remember that we are billed on the bandwidth limit !)

Is this a global change in Firebase database bandwidth measuring logic ?
We don't mind changement, by a x4 increase in a potential billing metric is never nice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, sort of. We didn't change the measurements, we just found that a bug was causing over half of the packets to be unaccounted for and we fixed that. So the bandwidth graph now more accurately represents your actual usage.

Typically it's best to reach out to firebase-support@google.com for this sort of question as there is no way for non-Firebasers to know the answer. That's also the best place to reach us if you're worried about unfair billing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, we did reached out to the support, however the explanations were not correct, hence this post.